# APCu not working on webserver

Tags: php, centos, cpanel, apc

I am trying to use APCu, i have re-installed everything lately but it seems as if APCu is not working.

I am using the following script to test if it can write the cache:

```
<?php
    // Simple Person class
    class Person {
        private $name;
        private $age;

        public function setName($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
        }

        public function setAge($age) {
            $this->age = $age;
        }

        public function getName() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        public function getAge() {
            return $this->age;
        }
    }

    // Check if Person object found from cache
    if ($obj = apc_fetch('person')) {
        echo "Person data from cache: ", "<br />";
        echo "Name: ", $obj->getName(), "<br />";
        echo "Age: ", $obj->getAge(), "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Person data not found from cache...saving', "<br />";
        $obj = new Person;
        $obj->setName('Test Person');
        $obj->setAge(35);
        apc_add('person', $obj, 3600);
    }
?>
```

Running this doesn't give me any errors but it alwasy says: "Person data not found..." which implicates that the cache is not working as it is supposed to.

In my php.ini i have configured it like this:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525"
extension=apcu.so

[apcu]

apc.enabled = 1
apc.shm_size=1024M
apc.max_file_size=10M
apc.num_files_hint=20000
apc.user_entries_hint=20000
```

I have recompiled everything but still no luck.

I am running the latest cpanel version. and phpinfo() also says that apcu is installed, i am running on CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work fine for me lets try

```
<?php
// Simple Person class
class Person {
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setAge($age) {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }
}

// Check if Person object found from cache
$obj = new Person;
    if (apc_fetch('person')) {
        $obj = apc_fetch('person');
        echo "Person data from cache: ", "<br />";
        echo "Name: ", $obj->getName(), "<br />";
        echo "Age: ", $obj->getAge(), "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Person data not found from cache...saving', "<br />";
        $obj->setName('Test Person');
        $obj->setAge(35);
        apc_add('person', $obj);
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have already tried multiple variants of the script without success.

Comment: It says, Person data from cache, Name: but it doesnt display the name and it doesnt even start on the age. Also APCu info still shows that nothing is being cached (0 request / second)

Comment: now this is working for your requirement but this only a sample

Comment: I am using your update code now but it says: Person data not found from cache...saving which implicates that its not being saved to the cache

Comment: i did try it more than 2 times

Comment: is else part ran every time?

Comment: try this code for only testing is your apc working or not ----apc_store('person',array('name'=>'abc','age'=>'10'));
    if (apc_fetch('person')) {
        $obj = apc_fetch('person');
        echo "Person data from cache: ", "<br />";
        echo "Name: ", $obj['name'], "<br />";
        echo "Age: ", $obj['age'], "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Person data not found from cache...saving', "<br />";
        $obj->setName('Test Person');
        $obj->setAge(35);
        apc_add('person', $obj);
    }

Comment: Seems to be working fine now, it doesn't run the else

Comment: can you get output in if part and print name and age ?

Comment: your api viewer not configured properly install api viewer according to your os from internet